# Calculating count of months from Json data in FTL

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, freemarker

I'm new to ftl, and I have a below json which is read by ftlh file. I'm trying to create a table where I need to combine columns of same month together. For this I will need to have count of same month from my json data. Here i need count of Nov month

Below is my json data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "startDate": {
                "displayName": "Start date",
                "value": "06-Nov-2023"
            },
            "hours": {
                "displayName": "Work hours",
                "value": "4"
            }
        },
        {
            "startDate": {
                "displayName": "Start date",
                "value": "13-Nov-2023"
            },
            "hours": {
                "displayName": "Work hours",
                "value": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "startDate": {
                "displayName": "Start date",
                "value": "20-Nov-2023"
            },
            "hours": {
                "displayName": "Work hours",
                "value": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "startDate": {
                "displayName": "Start date",
                "value": "27-Nov-2023"
            },
            "hours": {
                "displayName": "Work hours",
                "value": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do, but not sure how to proceed.

```
<#assign monthCounter = 0 >
        <#list detail.get("data").get("value").elements() as work>
            <#if (work.get("startDate").get("value").asText(""))?has_content>
                <#assign monthCounter = monthCounter + 1 />
                <#assign startDate = work.get("startDate").get("value").asText("")[3..5] />
            </#if>
        </#list>
```